# Can anyone tell me how I can change the font size of the \lstlistoflistings?

Tags: fontsize

I've suceeded in creating list of listings, but the font of the /lstlistoflistings is too large. I don't have any idea how to decrease it.

Comment: Do you mean the font size of the title "List of Listings", or the font size of the list items?

Comment: usually for **list of ...** the heading is a standard document section heading and the list itself is just set at `\normalsize` so it should not be "too large" and would not normally have its own font settings.  can you add a small example to your question that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the title a quick workaround is to include a size command in the name of the list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=A listing]
This is a listing
\end{lstlisting}
\def\lstlistlistingname{\small Listings}
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Changing the font size of the list items is more difficult. You can copy the definition of `\lstlistoflistings` from the package source and add a size command just before the `\tableofcontents` command in that definition. Also include `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the redefinition because the code contains `@` symbols. Here I used `\footnotesize` for the list items.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=A listing]
This is a listing
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=Another listing]
This is a listing
\end{lstlisting}
\def\lstlistlistingname{\small Listings}
\makeatletter
\def\lstlistoflistings{%
\bgroup \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname%
\let\lst@temp\@starttoc%
\def\@starttoc ##1{\lst@temp {lol}}%
\footnotesize% here the size command is added
\tableofcontents%
\egroup}
\makeatother
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But when I want to change the font size of the list below the title ?

Comment: @Konrad see edit.